# Unable to add "Created On" field to Information Form on "Article" Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am working on Dynamics CRM 2011 (Rollup 8). I want to add "Created On" Field to Information Form of "Article" entity.

I can't see the field in Field explorer and I am sure that field is not already used on form.

Is there any reason why I can't see the "Created On" field in list?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different forms that cannot be modified (much) and this happens to be one of them.

•   Article Template
•   Case Resolution
•   Connection Roles
•   Contract Template
•   Customer Relationship
•   Data Map
•   Dialog Session
•   Discount List
•   E-mail Attachment 
•   E-mail Template
•   Field Security Profile
•   Note
•   Opportunity Close
•   Opportunity Relationship
•   Order Close
•   Process
•   Publisher 
•   Quick Campaign
•   Quote Close
•   Resource Group
•   Saved View
•   Security Role
•   Service 
•   Site
•   Solution
•   Unit (mobile form)
•   Unit Group
•   View

You might have noticed that you cannot even create a new form for Articles (as you might be able to with other entities). Currently I don’t think there is a solution to this, just a limitation.

Comment: Thanks @Bactos. I also came to the same conclusion. CRM does not allow to add the OOB CreatedOn field on the Article form. I have sorted it by creating a custom field and populated it with javascript OnSave.